# How to verify an API request has not been made with Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

I have a chat application that I'm writing Playwright tests for. There is a `textbox` where the user can write their message. When the user presses `Enter`, the message should be sent. When the user presses `Shift+Enter`, the message should not be sent, but a line break should be added to the message.

How can I write Playwright tests for this? Here is a start:

```js
test("pressing enter should send message", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("/chat");

  const input = page.getByRole("textbox");

  await input.fill("foo");
  await input.press("Enter");
  await expect(input).toHaveValue("foo");

  // TODO: Expect that the form is submitted.
});

test("pressing shift+enter should create a line break", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("/chat");

  const input = page.getByRole("textbox");

  await input.fill("foo");
  await input.press("Enter");
  await expect(input).toHaveValue("foo\n"); // Can the line break be \r\n?

  // TODO: Expect that the form is not submitted
});
```

Comment: This is close to being a fairly clear question, but showing an example page would help make it easier to write a working, concrete answer. How does the page communicate form submission? Does it show some text on the page? Or will you need to intercept a request?

Comment: What is  precisely the  problem - how to perform 'shift+enter' or how to verify form is not submitted? Or both.

Comment: Currently as shared , both tests perform data input identically but expect different outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general , that's how I would verify an certain API request has **not** been made:

```
let fooRequestWasMade = false;
    page.on('request', request => {
      if (request.url().includes("/foobar/"))
        fooRequestWasMade = true
    })
    await page.keyboard.press('Shift+Enter')
    expect(fooRequestWasMade).toBe(false);
```